# order_id не сохраняется в БД (sqlite3, aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, sqlite3

Мейн-код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
import keyboards
from database import Database
from config import BOT_TOKEN, admin_id
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup


class Answer(StatesGroup):
    sended = State()
    answer = State()


bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
db = Database('database.db')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        await bot.send_message(admin_id, f'Зашел новый пользователь: @{message.from_user.username}')
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
    await message.answer('<b> Привет!</b>\n\nЧтобы воспользоваться ботом, нажимай на кнопки ниже.',
                         reply_markup=keyboards.main_keyboard)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def cmd_commands(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == ' Получить товар':
        await message.answer('Пожалуйста, напишите ID заказа (<b>введите только цифры</b>):')
        await Answer.sended.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Answer.sended)
async def cmd_sended(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    order_id = int(message.text)
    await state.update_data(
        {

            'order_id': order_id

        }

    )
    await message.answer('<b>Ваша заявка была отправлена администратору, ожидайте выдачи</b>')
    db.set_user_text(message.from_user.id, order_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

БД-файл:

```
import sqlite3


class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cur.execute("""INSERT into 'info' ('user_id') VALUES (?)""", (user_id,))

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.connection.execute("""SELECT * FROM "info" WHERE "user_id" = ?""", (user_id,)).fetchall()
        return bool(len(result))

    def set_user_text(self, user_id, order_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cur.execute("""UPDATE 'info' SET 'order_id' = ? WHERE 'user_id' = ?""",
                                    (order_id, user_id,))
```

Когда пользователь вводит integer в боте, это число не сохраняется в ячейку "order_id" в БД.

Answer (score 0):

После того как вы вносите изменения в базу данных функцией `execute()` то вам необходимо подтвердить изменения при помощи функции `commit()`, пример:

```
def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cur.execute("""INSERT into 'info' ('user_id') VALUES (?)""", (user_id,))
            self.connection.commit()
            return result
```

Comment: все равно ничего не происходит